# Does the product function $fg$, where $f$ is in $L^2$ and $g$ is in $C^{\infty}_0$ belong to hardy space $H^1$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am struggling to know whether the product function $fg$, where $f$ is in $L^2$ and $g$ is in $C^{\infty}_0$ belong to hardy space $H^1$.
$fg$ has compact support but I can't figure out how I can try to find a atomic decomposition with cancellation property. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An $H^1$ function has zero mean, but there's no reason for $fg$ to have this property.

Comment: If by Hardy space you mean the complex Hardy space then obviously no, since $fg$ has no reason to be holomorphic; if you mean the real Hardy space then obviously yes, since locally the maximal function belongs to $L^2$, thus also to $L^1$.

Comment: Dear Alexander Shamov, thank you very much! I meant real hardy space $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ Could you please clarify what maximal function do you use here? It seems there are several equivalent definitions for $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: @AlexanderShamov: This is incorrect; you ignore the necessary (and, here, also sufficient) condition I mentioned in my comment for a function to belong to the real Hardy space (if you want to look at the maximal function, then this will not decay fast enough as $x\to\pm\infty$ unless $fg$ has zero mean). See here also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Real_Hardy_spaces_for_Rn

Comment: @DulguunDarkhan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function. Christian is right - there is a local version and a homogeneous version; if you need the latter one, it imposes the zero mean condition.

Comment: The original proflem is I wanted to make sense the term $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fg\phi$ where $f$ is in $BMO$ and $g$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\phi$ is in $C^{\infty}_0$. Using duality between $BMO(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, I want $g\phi$ is in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So this is made sure, since  $g\phi$  is compactly supported. According to Alexander, I may needed local real Hardy space $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Thank you Christian!

Comment: @DulguunDarkhan: The $H^1$-$BMO$ duality is way too fancy as a tool here. You can just observe that $f\in BMO$ is locally in $L^2$, and that's enough to make the integral converge. ($BMO$ functions are not very far from being bounded: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation#BMO_functions_are_locally_p.E2.80.93integrable )

Answer (score -2):

This is obvious not sure, aמ obvious concentrate example is :
The step function $f(x)$ of closed interval $[0,1]$,

It can be expressed as $\ f(x) = g(x)h(x)\\$, with $g(x) \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ is a cut function, and $h(x)=f(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. But $f(x)$ itself is not in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$, because $f'(x) =\delta(1) - \delta(0)$, which is not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, in general, all step function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are also counter examples.

Comment: I am not really convinced. $fg$ is product not convolution. What do you mean by f' =delta(1) - delta(0). Is it derivative? Why f is not in H1(R) because of  f' =delta(1) - delta(0).

Comment: sorry!i misunderstanding the question at first,i lisp it and misunderstanding the space $H1$ to $W1,1$,but i should point out in the hardy space case this is also not true,the point is Hp(T) is the closed subspace of Lp(T) and f contain in Hp(T) iff f contain in Lp(T) and for any n negative integer ,the fourior series f(n)=0. and the fourior series of fg is convolution of f's and g's,so Hp is not closed under